# Suppress linear referencing M-values in FME

Tags: fme-form

I'm creating an FME workspace to copy a line feature class from an ArcSDE database to PostGIS. I've been getting the error `Column has Z dimension but geometry does not`. It turns out the "Z-dimension" is actually referring to M-values (for routing purposes). I don't need them in the target database so I'd like to just keep them out of the transformation for now. Does anyone know how to do this in FME? I don't see any settings in my reader or writer.

Comment: use the MeasureRemover https://www.safe.com/transformers/measure-remover/ to remove M z values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Mapperz has indicated, you should use the **[MeasureRemover](http://docs.safe.com/fme/2016.0/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/measureremover.htm)**.  You can specify the name of the measure (if known), or you can remove all measures from the features.

[image]

If it is in fact Z-values that you need to remove, then the **[2DForcer](http://docs.safe.com/fme/2016.0/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/2dforcer.htm)** is the transformer to use.